# High losing of quality after rendering sony vegas pro 17

Tags: vegas-pro, rendering, quality, lossless

I am rendering a video of resolution 2704 x 1520 of 50 FPS on sony vegas.
Here are the parameters of the videos :

[image]

I'm trying to render for a clip video on **youtube**. However I have an important loss of quality.

Here are my render parameters :

[image]

And here pictures of the differences between original video and rendered video :

Rendered :

[image]

Original :

[image]

It is a just a screenshot but you can see that the colors and the details on the rendered videos are less better.
Does someone have an idea to match the rendered quality and the original video quality?
Thank you

EDIT : I already disabled resampling

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem over and over again. I've read tons of "good advices" on many forums and watched quite a bit of videos on YT and never found any satisfactory answer that's why I decided never again to come close to this program. Vegas Pro has the best UI and is the most user friendly video editor on the market (I can't speak for Final Cut Pro as I work on a PC) but the rendering quality is among the worst, with a huge degradation of the original videos in the rendering process probably due to crappy codecs which the manufacturer has no idea how to improve. I'll never ever touch Vegas Pro again. Now I'm trying Premiere Pro and the quality of the rendered videos are SUPERB but some basic features (like transitions which I use all the time) are much worse than in any other program I've experienced with which could make Premiere Pro a difficult choice for some.